# Is there a solution to Global Secondary Index on map, list in Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb structure for a user that contains the list, map along with scalar indexes like email_id(primary key), phone_number, etc. 
My map(pols) contains pol_number, pol_name, activated(boolean), etc.

I want to query based on the map with pol_number.

Some of the solutions in stack-overflow say to create a new table with primary key as pol_number which I don't want to since my data is already in production.

Is there a possible solution?

```
{
  "email_id" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "phone_number" : "567896545678",
  "pols" : [
     {
        "pol_number" : "123"(unique for my application),
        "activated" : true,
        "pol_name" : "hdhsjfs",
     },
     {
        "pol_number" : "123"(unique for my application),
        "activated" : true,
        "pol_name" : "hdhsjfs",
     }
  ]
}
```